# bash loop in parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run this script in parallel, for i<=4 in each set. The `runspr.py` is itself parallel, and thats fine. What I am trying to do is running only 4 i loop in any instance.

In my present code, it will run everything.

```
#!bin/bash
for i in *
do 
  if [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "$i id dir"
    cd $i
      python3 ~/bin/runspr.py SCF &
  cd ..
  else
    echo "$i nont dir"
  fi
done
```

I have followed https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35416/four-tasks-in-parallel-how-do-i-do-that 
but unable to impliment the code in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `for` loop. You can use [`gnu parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) like this with `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -print0 |
parallel -0 --jobs 4 'cd {}; python3 ~/bin/runspr.py SCF'
```

Comment: Also try: `parallel 'cd {}; python3 ~/bin/runspr.py SCF' ::: */`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -print0 |
xargs -I {} -P 4 sh -c 'cd {}; python3 ~/bin/runspr.py SCF'
```